# Running a query against all tables

Tags: sql, sqlite

I'd like to run a query against all tables in a SQLite database.

So for example, something like:

```
SELECT SUM(values), name, DATE(date_col) FROM tablename
```

using the master table I tried using a subquery, but obviously it wasn't working:

```
SELECT SUM(values), name, DATE(date_col)
FROM (SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table')
GROUP BY name, DATE(date_col)
```

I can certainly do it manually, but why do that when I can optimise and future-proof?

Does anyone have any suggestions? Is this even possible in a single query?

Thanks

Comment: When the columns and/or tables you want to select from in a query are not pre-known, you have to use dynamic sql. I doubt this is possible in sqlite.

Comment: If SqlLite won't support dynamic SQL for you, use another tool, perhaps Excel or Access, to build and run the dynamic query.

Comment: Thanks both. I just did it manually instead.